# Is LibreTexts allowable as a reference for formal research?

Tags: citations, peer-review

I am currently writing a paper that has a potential to be published. It is mathematics-heavy, so a lot of the sources I encountered are something like libretexts, paul's online notes, etc. My main sources are online textbooks and physical textbooks. Is it acceptable to cite them? The thing with a mathematics-heavy paper is its very hard to find "peer-reviewed" articles that are suitable for what you're writing. The theoretical concept you need to support the paper will easily come from a textbook.

Comment: Generally, if what you are relying on is textbooks, what you are doing is probably not at the frontiers of research and is already known or easily derived from what is in the literature (and hence not publishable), even if the derivation is obvious only to experts.  Are you sure that your paper is actually publishable in a decent journal?

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the formulation. Is it a paper on mathematics, or is it a paper in another field that, however, uses a lot of math? In the latter case, is it a field in which the generic audience tends to have insufficient mathematical training to follow the argument and needs help even finding suitable references?

Answer (score 5):

It is fine to cite actual textbooks that are published by reputable academic publishers. However, online mathematics lecture notes are poorly vetted sources and often contain errors. (I say this not just based on my experience reading lecture notes, but as someone who posted various lecture notes online, some of which eventually evolved into actual textbooks. I can attest that the difference in reliability between lecture notes and textbooks is *huge*, as is the effort required to transform lecture notes into textbooks.)

Thus, I would say the credibility of lecture notes as a resource for citing is low, and you should avoid as much as possible citing them. If I were refereeing a paper that relied on such citations I would very possibly give you trouble over this. By relying on such sources you risk misleading yourself as much as your readers.

> The thing with a mathematics-heavy paper is its very hard to find "peer-reviewed" articles that are suitable for what you're writing.

This has not been my experience. I tend to agree with @AlexanderWoo, if you are only citing textbooks then it seems quite likely that your research is not at the cutting edge of knowledge and your results may not be as publishable as you think. Moreover, Paul's online notes is a website with tutorials about undergraduate level math. I cannot imagine a research-level  math paper that would need to cite anything from there, so if you are under the impression that it contains anything useful for citing, you may have serious misconceptions about what math research is and what counts as publishable work. In that case I'd recommend that you look for an experienced mentor to discuss your ideas with and get detailed feedback from.

> The theoretical concept you need to support the paper will easily come from a textbook.

Good, so find a proper textbook to cite - one that was actually edited and polished by competent people and that a reputable publisher is putting their credibility behind.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* cite anything you want. But you're asking the wrong question - if all of your sources are textbooks and online learning resources, is the work actually publishable? Why isn't there peer reviewed literature to support it?

I have cited textbooks and other material before. I don't think there is fundamentally anything wrong with it. I sometimes work on multidisciplinary projects and it can be nice to include background on a topic that may be simple/basic to an expert in field A but not to one in field B.

But if the *core* of your paper can be explained or found in a free online textbook, that could be an issue. Maybe the topic isn't really novel. Or it might be a dead end (that others have explored already).

I don't work in mathematics though, so maybe I'm off base.